# RavenDB: Add auto increment to other property than ID in Raven 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, ravendb, auto-increment

Prior to 4.0 I could set an auto incremental property as mentioned in [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637947/ravendb-add-auto-increment-to-other-property-than-id)

But with 4.0 IDocumentStoreListener,HiLoKeyGenerator has been removed. Yet I can catch the event of saving a doc like [this on Raven Doc](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.0/Csharp/client-api/session/how-to/subscribe-to-events). But no way to generate an incremental ID. Is there a workaround for this. ?

```
    public class Product 
    {
       public string Id {get; set;}
       public int OtherIncrementalId {get; set;} 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Docs about custom id generation based on type:
https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.0/csharp/client-api/configuration/identifier-generation/type-specific

if you want to customize the id generation for all types i tried with this and it works:

```
 documentStore.Conventions.RegisterAsyncIdConvention<object>((dbname, obj) =>
 {
    return Task.FromResult(DocumentConventions.DefaultGetCollectionName(obj.GetType())+"/"+ YourCustomFunctionToGetNextId());
 });
```